# vs code C++ include list of paths

Tags: header, include, visual-studio-code

I am using C++ in vs code and would like to automatically pull in changing external include paths that for clang to find. Currently I have to edit the `c_cpp_properties.json` file as so:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/some/path/headers1/**",
                "/some/path/headers2/**",
                "/some/path/headers3/**",
                ...
                "/some/path/headersN/**"
            ],
            ...    
        }
    ],
}
```

Can I instead do something like this?

```
{
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Linux",
                "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/headers.txt"
                ],
                ...    
            }
        ],
    }
```

Where `${workspaceFolder}/headers.txt` is:

```
/some/path/headers1/
/some/path/headers2/
/some/path/headers3/
```

OR

```
"/some/path/headers1/**",
"/some/path/headers2/**",
"/some/path/headers3/**"
```

to be compliant with the original json includePath format. **So there a way for me to reference the `${workspaceFolder}/headers.txt` in the `c_cpp_properties.json` so that I don't have to manually update the paths?**